# drupal_http_request send Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request when spaces

Tags: php, http, drupal, httprequest, freebase

drupal_http_request send "`Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request`" when spaces in url:

```
$uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=&prefixed=true&limit=10&output=(type )&lang=en";
 $options = array(
  'method' => 'GET',
  'timeout' => 3,
  'headers' => array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
  ),
);

$result = drupal_http_request($uri, $options);
```

" **&output=(type )** " there is space after type . if i remove space then its working fine. but space give 400 bad request error. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'proper' Drupal way:

```
$service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search';
$params = array(
  'query' => $search_string,
  'output' => '(description owner)',
  'filter' => '(any type:product type:brand)',
  'limit' => YILD_FREEBASE_MAX_HITS,
  'prefixed' => 'true',
  'lang' => $lang ,
);

$uri = url($serivce_url, array('query' => $params, 'external' => TRUE));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search';
  $params = array(
    'query' => $search_string,
    'output' => '(description owner)',
    'filter' => '(any type:product type:brand)',
    'limit' => YILD_FREEBASE_MAX_HITS,
    'prefixed' => 'true',
    'lang' => $lang ,

  );
$uri = $service_url . '?' . http_build_query($params);
```

This solve my problem .